# Is it possible to download and configure jenkins with a script?

Tags: shell-script, docker, jenkins

I want to develop a continuous integration with one or many scripts locally and then on a server.

For that I need Jenkins. I installed jenkins in a docker container, but would it be possible to configure it with a script so that the configuration can be used on any computer that runs it? When I talk about configuration, I'm talking about jenkins jobs and plugins.

Comment: Why not? Pretty much anything can be scripted.

Comment: Not only is it possible, but it's already been done: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You can write groovy scripts to configure Jenkins via the script console.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console

Using this I have in the past configures jobs, folders and security.

You can load scripts in from within Jenkins or push them in via HTTP or the CLI

To clarify:

Create a groovy script to configure the jobs.

Include it in your docker configuration.

Have docker run the script to create the jobs on deployment of the container.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenStack](https://openstack.org) maintains the [Jenkins Job Builder](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/) python module that can use YAML configuration to spin up jobs.